# Android show a full span dynamic view in between Grid Layout Manager items in Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` showing a list of images in grid. My requirement is to display the details about the image below it when an image is clicked and hide it when clicked again. The description view spans the complete width as shown in the attached image:

[image: Requirement Image]

Could someone please suggest how to do the description part of the requirement.
Any suggestions are welcome and will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use SetOnClickListener method in Viewholder.There you can write code if layout(your details layout) is showing hide or show.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. It's helpful to add example code that allows the user to implement your suggestion quickly and accurately.

Comment: I already tried that...but the layout is not spanning the complete width but only till the width of the clicked image

Comment: `I already tried that...but the layout is not spanning the complete width but only till the width of the clicked image` you will have to change the no of spans (`GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup`)

Comment: @Blackbelt Could you show code sample to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was able to solve it using the combination of SpanSizeLookup and heterogeneous recycler view type where the description data is added to the layout dynamically.